# Pivot just one column without knowing the values of that column

Tags: python, pandas

I will need to pivot a column in pandas, would greatly appreciate any help.

Input:

| ID | Status | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Online | 2022-06-31 |
| 1 | Offline | 2022-07-28 |
| 2 | Online | 2022-08-01 |
| 3 | Online | 2022-07-03 |
| 3 | None | 2022-07-05 |
| 4 | Offline | 2022-05-02 |
| 5 | Online | 2022-04-04 |
| 5 | Online | 2022-04-06 |

Output: Pivot on **Status**

| ID | Date | Online | Offline | None |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-06-31 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 2022-07-28 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 2022-08-01 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 2022-07-03 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 2022-07-05 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 2022-05-02 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 5 | 2022-04-04 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 2022-04-06 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

Or even better output if I am able to merge the counts for example:

Output: Pivot on **Status & merge**

| ID | Online | Offline | None |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 | 0 | 0 |

The main issue here is that I won't know the status values i.e. Offline, Online, None.

I believe doing it in pandas might be easier due to the dynamic nature of not knowing column values for the column I want to pivot on.

Comment: `pd.crosstab(df['id'], df['Status']).reset_index()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.assign(seq=1).pivot_table(index='ID', columns='Status', values='seq', aggfunc='sum').fillna(0)
```

```
Status  None    Offline     Online
ID          
1   0.0     1.0     1.0
2   0.0     0.0     1.0
3   1.0     0.0     1.0
4   0.0     1.0     0.0
5   0.0     0.0     2.0
```